# How to make per user base logging with hapi js

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I am using winston logging framework and logging on basis of log level, but now i am facing difficulties in tracking down bugs. So we decided to make logging on per user basis, and this is where i ran into problem.

**What i want to acheive?**

- log file for every user will be generated on every hour. (We can skip every hour constraint in this thread) and every user has unique identifier 'uid'.

**What i have?**

- I have followed architecture as used here 'https://github.com/agendor/sample-hapi-rest-api'. Some additional lib modules exist too.
- Currently i am using winston library (but i can afford to replace this if needed).

**Brief introduction of flow**

- Currently, i have access to request object in handler function only, but i want to log events in DAO, library functions too ( on per user basis). 'Uid' is available to me in handler function in request object as i put uid in request in authentication middleware.

**My solution (which is not elegant)**

- pass request object ( or only uid) to every function and log (using winston) event. Custom transport will determine where (in which file, on basis of uid) to put the log.
  Certainly, this is not elegant way as every function must have uid parameter in order to log event, which seems bad.

**What i want from you?**

- A better, elegant approach which is scalable too.

Related post: https://github.com/hapijs/discuss/issues/51

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking a look at Continuation-Local Storage:
https://github.com/othiym23/node-continuation-local-storage

Heres a good article on implementing it within express:
https://datahero.com/blog/2014/05/22/node-js-preserving-data-across-async-callbacks/